# Best practice handling 403

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We have an angular application built in MVC (Authentication to AAD using owin). When accessing actions with authorize attributes, Angular gets a 403 as expected. I can catch this perfectly:

```
factory('responseObserver', function responseObserver($q, $window) {
    return {
        'responseError': function (errorResponse) {
            switch (errorResponse.status) {
                case 403:
                    $window.location = 'Account/NotAuthorized';
                    break;
                case 500:
                    $window.location = './500.html';
                    break;
            }
            return $q.reject(errorResponse);
        }
```

However if I login with an authorized user, get some data, logout and login  , again with a not authorized user, the data from the old user is shown due to the nature SPA. What is best practices here? Can you somehow clear all data, or scope it to a specific user? I am thinking I could implement a signoff that clears all data first and then do a real sign-off.

Comment: is it angular v1? are you clearing data on logout?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you see I allready catch the forbidden response. In the suggested thread, I dont see and information on how to clear the scope/data. I dont know typescript so I may be wrong?

Comment: Are you in AngularJs or Angular(2+)?

Comment: Angular 1 version 1.65

Comment: I retagged the question, that may help you to get the appropriated help :)